# Behat follow links with html in it

Tags: behat, mink

I have a response similar to

```
<a href="..."><span>1</span> widget</a>
```

and a feature like

```
Feature: My feature

  Scenario: My Scenario
   Given I am on the homepage
   Then I should see a "1 widget"
```

This will obviously fail because of the span tag. What is the proper way to assert the text is present or follow the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to check the text,

```
Then I should see text matching "pattern"
```

If you're able to modify the HTML, adding a unique ID attribute to the link would be the easiest way to click it. If that's not possible, can could use a CSS selector to locate the link element and then click it. Something like this in your step (note: untested code!),

```
$node = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', 'your css selector');
$node->click();
```